# Vuelidate Dropdown/Select Validation

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Vuelidate is not able to validate a Select/Dropdown element?

```
HTML

<div  :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.subscription.$error }">
              <label for="">Year Subscription</label>
              <select name="subscription" @change="subscriptionChange()" v-model="$v.subscription.$model" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
JS Code

subscription  : {required }
```